# How do I change tty / text console resolution without rebooting?

Tags: tty

fbset is not an option. It doesn't apply any change "live". Also, fbset is not even useful. It looks like it's only going to display current settings.

Answer (score 3):

Running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` changes the font size of all your consoles without rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

I saw suggestions to change font size, but it is not the same as changing actual resolution.
I thought that there should be some file to which we can put our wanted resolution, like this:

```
echo 1920x900 > /some/file/current_resolution
```

Or maybe some hack to programmable unplug and then replug video output again with suggested resolution (so it's like a reinitialization of kms).

But actutally I have discovered that **fbset** *is* a solution. There is [the same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499420/264065) on a more generic unix.stackexchange site, but 
It works even for ubuntu, so I decided to also write an answer here.
Use it as follows:

```
fbset -xres 1920 -yres 900
```